# Subtle conditions that imply linear independence

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-independence

Suppose you have a set of $2 < k < n$ non-zero, distinct vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with non-negative integer coefficients such that the sum of the entries of each vector is equal to the same positive integer $c$. I want to ensure the vectors in this set are linearly independent. My hope is that since I already have two assumptions on these vectors, I do not have to add full blown linear independence as a further assumption, but there is a weaker one (no matter if convoluted or complicated) that would ensure they are. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

No, $2<k<n$ is not enough. Let $n=4$,  $k=3$, and let $c=6$. Consider the following example:
$$
u=\begin{pmatrix} 1 \cr 1 \cr 1 \cr 3\end{pmatrix},\;
v=\begin{pmatrix} 1\cr 1 \cr 3 \cr 1\end{pmatrix},\;
w=\begin{pmatrix} 1\cr 1 \cr 2 \cr 2\end{pmatrix},\; 
$$
They are not linearly independent, since $u+v=2w$. One can extend this example by adding further entries $1$ in $u,v,w$. So three vectors are already too many. So we need $k=2$ or $k=1$.

Comment: Of course $k < n$ vectors, no doubt. I edited, thank you. I know I need more, the point is what is the smallest assumption I need given that I already have other assumptions.

Comment: There is no "smallest", because our set of possible assumptions need not have a least element. A "small" assumption is, just to allow sets with $1$ element, and not all entries equal to zero.

Comment: Of course. Anything "smaller" than linear independence itself works.

Comment: No, exactly, what I'm looking for should work for more vectors. It's probably a trickier question than it seems.

Comment: Done, thanks for your remarks, you helped me improve the question @Dietrich Burde

Comment: There is no doubt that with my current assumptions there are infinitely many counterexamples. What I mean is: are there *additional* assumptions, weaker than imposing linear independence, that ensure the vectors are linearly independent?

Comment: "Weaker than linear independence" is not enough, because it may be pointless, like requiring $k=1$, or similar unpleasant assumptions. It remains unclear whether or not one can find something *reasonable* except for saying they need to be linearly independent. This is not yet clear. Some more counterexamples might be helpful. In principle, you have to forbid all those counterexamples.

Comment: I agree, that's why I asked the question